# Анимация изменения размера иконок на Yandex картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть задача реализовать плавно увеличение/уменьшение иконки (Placemark) на карте.

Знаю что можно задать размеры иконки следующим образом:
`map.geoObjects.get(0).options.set("iconImageSize", [72, 72])`
Этим способом иконка меняет размер сразу же на заданный, без анимации.

Я сделал функцию работающую на интервалах, которая "анимирует" изменение размера, но иконка дергается, пропадает на доли секунд и появляется после окончания конца анимации.

Собственно вопрос: есть ли нативный способ анимировать размер иконки?

Answer (score 0):

Может в качестве изображения проще добавить gif анимацию?

```
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageHref: 'https://www.qmedia.by/assets/templates/qmedia/img/preloader2.gif',
    iconImageSize: [160, 160],
    iconImageOffset: [-80, -80]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83pwk6j5/

Comment: Нет. Вы не поняли вопрос. В вашем случае идёт простая анимация иконки. А мне, к примеру, нужно чтобы по клику на какой-нибудь объект нужная иконка плавно становилась больше в размерах.

Comment: У JS API  Карт нет анимаций иконок.